# Implementing a Typescript Function-With-State-Interface

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

Given the interface below. How do I actually implement it? I'm having a hard time coming up with the correct syntax for the function call.

```
export interface IFoo<T> {
    (newValue?: T): T;
    state: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
var tmp: any = function(newValue = 'Hello!') {
    return newValue;
}
tmp.state = 123;
var foo: IFoo<string> = tmp;

console.log(foo.state);
console.log(foo());
```